# Regex to forbid any space before or after apostrophes and hyphens

Tags: regex, validation, input

i need detail validation with this requirement:

1. Accept Alphabet (A-Z or a-z)
2. May include this special char (åçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]*$)
3. Accept Spaces, apostrophes and hyphens
4. Can using apostrophes and hyphens between non space character, example:

- `Le'brahm`
- `Ben-John`

cannot accept `Le' brahm` or `Ben -John` or `Ben- John`

I use this regex currently but cannot fullfill the number 4 requirements
and number 3 partially

```
^[a-zA-Z åçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]*$
```

if i added hypens like this

```
^[a-zA-Z -'åçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]*$
```

the regex become error and it accepts number character (should be not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]+(?:[-' ][a-zA-Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]+)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EXWsK1/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `[a-zA-Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]+`: Matches 1+ of given letters inside `[...]`
- `(?:[-' ][a-zA-Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]+)*`: Matches 0 or more of same set of characters separated by `-` or `'` or a space.

Comment: hi, im using Swift for my iphone app, it almost done, just still when i am using ' 
like O'Niel, it doesnt work well

Comment: But it matches word `O'Niel`

Comment: yeah, from those website, it passed, but not on my swift code, very weird, because - works fine, but not on '

Comment: do u know why in iOS, it doesnt read the ' thing ? it is just only that left,

i have tried to make it like ^[a-zA-Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]+(?:['- ][a-zA-Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ]+)*$

but it caused crash

Comment: If you shown your code by editing question then I can check

Comment: Your code looks fine to me though I am not a swift developer.

Answer (score 1):

Use lookarounds:

```js
^(?!.*[-'‘’ ]{2})(?![-'‘’ ])(?!.*[-'‘’ ]$)[a-zA-Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóúñ '‘’-]+$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/U9VEGc/2).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-‘’' ]{2}               any character of: '-', ''', ' ', '‘', '’' (2
                             times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-'‘’ ]                    any character of: '-', ''', ' ', '‘', '’'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-'‘’ ]                    any character of: '-', ''', ' ', '‘', '’'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-                    any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
  Zåçêëèïîìæôöòûùÿáíóú     'å', 'ç', 'ê', 'ë', 'è', 'ï', 'î', 'ì',
  ñ '‘’-]+                   'æ', 'ô', 'ö', 'ò', 'û', 'ù', 'ÿ', 'á',
                           'í', 'ó', 'ú', 'ñ', ' ', ''', '-', '‘', '’' (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```